# How to redirect a page to another page if the focus to the page is lost in java script

Tags: javascript, .net, redirect

Suppose if a user opens a new tab then automatically the old tab has to be redirected to some default page.

In ranksheet website when an user is writing the exam if he opens new tab then exam will be stopped and the page will be redirected to another page. How is that possible in Java Script

Comment: ASP is a server side technology. What you want happens purely on the client so you are completely on the wrong track. Look for something like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
window.onblur = function(){
    location.href="http://google.com";
    window.onblur = '';
}
```

Comment: No, clicking the address bar is triggering the blur event on the page. The `window.onbeforeunload` could be used instead, but it won't stop anyone from opeing a new tab or window. What problem are we trying to solve? I think you might be on the wrong track.